# How to add conditional fragment with it's value to the anchor html tag in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm loading menus from service and need to conditionally add the fragment to anchor. here the problem is fragment add # for the empty value and don't want to add # in URL for an empty fragment.

see the following HTML code of navbar component.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">
       <a [routerLink]="menu.menuUrl" [title]="menu.name" here need to add fragment with it's value if menu.fragment present>
          <span>{{menu.name}}</span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use ngSwitch to display the menu according to the value of menu.fragment

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li *ngFor="let menu of menus" [ngSwitch]="menu.fragment !== undefined">
    <a *ngSwitchCase="true" [fragment]="menu.fragment" [routerLink]="menu.menuUrl" [title]="menu.name">
      <span>{{menu.name}}</span>
    </a>
    <a *ngSwitchDefault [routerLink]="menu.menuUrl" [title]="menu.name" >
      <span>{{menu.name}} no frag</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can find a running example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxp2dx